# GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(Intent) returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-geofence

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) tutorial using Java. As expected the BroadcastReceiver receives an Intent, but the  `GeofencingEvent fromIntent (Intent intent)` method returns NULL.
According to the docs for `fromIntent`:

> returns - a GeofencingEvent object or null if the given intent is null
> or doesn't contain geofencing event

What are possible reasons?

Answer (score 10):

While i wrote this question i noticed the error:
In newer versions `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` forces you to choose either `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_UNMUTABLE`. I chose FLAG_UNMUTABLE...
Obviously the Intent cant get filled with GeofenceEvent Information if its not mutable...